# How can I change the privacy settings for all events on my Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

I have quite a few events in my Google Calendar and they are all set to Default privacy.

My Google Calendar sharing preferences is currently set to "Show free/busy only":

[image: free/busy]

But I would like to change this to "see all event details", and change all of the existing events from "Default" privacy to "Private" - so that all new events I create will be public - but existing events are private.

[image: options]

How can I change the privacy setting for all existing events to Private without having to change them one at a time? I have looked at the Google Calendar webpage and also in iCal and have not found an option in either, and actually in iCal I don't think there are any privacy settings that show up at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a way to do this through the web interface.  However, it is fairly straight forward if you download the ICS file, remove all lines which begin with "PRIVACY:", and upload it as a new calendar.

e.g. `grep -v ^CLASS: old.ics > new.ics`

http://www.dataliberation.org/google/calendar